# Excel Pivot Table Filter Sum of Time Range

Tags: excel, filtering, pivot-table

I am having problems while filtering in a Pivot Table. I guess it seems not to work because of the format, here is an example.

Table in sheet looks like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83MJh.jpg)

Column D is "Time" and calculates the difference of ColumnB-ColumnC, i.e. D2= C2-B2
Cells in column D are formatted as "Time" 37:30:55

With this table a created a Pivot as shown in the picture below:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdauK.jpg)

If I now want to filter column B or C in the Pivot table for a time i.e. greater than 10:00:00 the filter does not work.

I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong, do you have any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: I have added the Pivot Table Fields to image 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the ID field using the Values filter setting:
[image]

...which works just fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! But it seems I am doing something wrong, when I try to filter for ID as in your example it filters for the "Grand Total" column but not for A or B. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ahh. Gotcha. For that, you need to move your TransferType field to the Rows pane, and filter theTransferType column. 

You can't filter it as a CrossTab like you are trying to do, because Excel doesn't know what to do in the event say that A is < 10 but B is > 10 for a particular item.

Comment: Great, thanks for this, works now the way I want it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have your Pivot Table Fields set properly. For example, what is the "Sum of Time Row Labels" in your Pivot Table? I see nothing that correlates in your original data sheet.

Can you provide a screenshot of your pivot table fields?

Comment: "Sum of Time Row Labels" in the Pivot Table sums up all times for identical IDs (from column A in the raw data sheet, see image 1)

Comment: Makes sense now. Back to your original problem ... what happens when you try and filter for time? It looks like it should work properly